# Comma usage in a complex series

Tags: commas

I have the following caption title:

Fig. 5. Measured small-signal gain, input return loss, and output return loss vs. frequency of C-band HPA.

This is equivalent to (a), (b), and (c) vs. (d)

**Question**

Ambiguity lies in the above as to whether (a), (b), and (c) are **all** versus (d) or whether it is simply a list of three things. Pleas help with the correct use of punctuation to illustrate the former case.

Comment: Won't the answer be obvious from the graph?

Comment: Although this question may have an answer, you can probably do better than relying on punctuation to make your meaning clear.

Comment: Snailboat - feel free to expand upon exactly how I can do better please.

Comment: Erik Kowal - it may be the case, but what would you do if there wasn't a graph?

Comment: If it's a graph, the captions is correct, go ahead. If not, and you suspect any ambiguity, please elaborate why.

Answer (score 2):

I would reverse the order:

> Fig. 5. Frequency of C-band HPA versus measured small-signal gain, input return loss, and output return loss.

There is still a slight opportunity for ambiguity but this form is much more likely to associate the entire list as being compared to the "frequency of C-band HPA."

Answer (score -1):

Could you just stick in an *all* as you have used in your explanation of how it could be misinterpreted?

> This is equivalent to (a), (b) and (c) **all** vs. (d)

Answer (score -2):

If you really have to, you can use an extra set of parentheses or square brackets to make it unmistakably clear. You might also label the two entities you're comparing:

```
This is equivalent to figures (a), (b), and (c) vs. figure (d).
```